# Openshift: cannot connect to my app

Tags: ssh, openshift-online-2

I have two apps in openshift and until yesterday everthing worked well.

Yesterday my page (Jboss cartidge) stop working and I cannot connect to this app using ssh. To the other app I can connect without a problem but this one no.

To connect, I did try by putty and my ubuntu box using the rhc ssh , and nothing worked. Also I did try to restart (several times) the app and also nothing. My last effort was trying to run command tiddy but even this did not work. - I follow the guide in openshift page

The error of ssh is "Permission denied (publickey, gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"

Someone knows what to do next?

Thanks

**Edit:** I don't know if this help but when I run "rhc setup" also gives me:

```
(...)
Checking for git ... found git version 1.9.1

Checking common problems .

An SSH connection could not be established to
standard-projectxserver.rhcloud.com. Your SSH configuration may not be correct,
or the application may not be responding. Authentication failed for user
556986ad500446e4320000fb@standard-projectxserver.rhcloud.com
(Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)

Checking for a domain ... projectxserver

Checking for applications ... found 1

  standard http://standard-projectxserver.rhcloud.com/
(...)
```

Comment: Do you need an SSH key to login? If it suddenly stopped working, maybe permissions on the key got changed, but this is just a guess…

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Is your account in good standing?

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I can loggin to my webconsole (or account in the openshift page) and I can loggin by ssh to my other app. This one I cannot. Also I run the command: "rhc app-show standard --gears quota" gives me error on Used quota (but before says Unable to connect to gear 556986ad500446e4320000fb@standard-projectxserver.rhcloud.com
)

Comment: I was having this issue till last night. But today it started working on all of a sudden without any intervention. May be it was a temporary issue at openshift.